# Purpose of Scala trait extending AnyVal?

Tags: scala, traits, value-class, universal-trait

Sometimes in Scala/Scala.js I see `trait Foo extends AnyVal { ... }` – what's the meaning and purpose of `extends AnyVal` here?

I'm aware of [value](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) [classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html#universal-traits), and that they can not extend traits that extend `AnyRef`, so using `extends AnyVal` would make sense for that use case.

But what if we don't use value classes to extend such a trait? Are there any performance advantages for traits to extend `AnyVal` on their own?

Comment: Nikita, It would probably be easier to answer your question if you provided some specific examples of such `trait`s that make you wonder. P.S. I don't think there is any performance advantage except for value classes.

Comment: 1. Is it really `extends AnyVal`, not `Any`? 2. If you don't extend such a trait with a value class it doesn't mean nobody does.